# how to correctly parse RSS XML with rometools?

Tags: java, xml, rss

I'm trying to parse a RSS XML file with `rometools`, but I haven't been able to get it working. The `Product` class bellow, has all the elements from the following RSS XML file. But I can't seem to be able to corretly map the file to the entity.

RSS XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>Test Store</title>
<link>http://www.example.com</link>
<description>An example item from the feed</description>
<item>
<g:id>DB_1</g:id>
<g:title>Dog Bowl In Blue</g:title>
<g:description>Solid plastic Dog Bowl in marine blue color</g:description>
<g:link>http://www.example.com/bowls/db-1.html</g:link>
<g:image_link>http://images.example.com/DB_1.png</g:image_link>
<g:brand>Example</g:brand>
<g:condition>new</g:condition>
<g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
<g:price>9.99 GBP</g:price>
<g:shipping>
<g:country>UK</g:country>
<g:service>Standard</g:service>
<g:price>4.95 GBP</g:price>
</g:shipping>
<g:google_product_category>Animals &gt; Pet Supplies</g:google_product_category>
<g:custom_label_0>Made in Waterford, IE</g:custom_label_0>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

The parsing method is:

```
Product product = new Product();

try {
    SyndFeedInput input = new SyndFeedInput();

    SyndFeed feed = input.build(new XmlReader(file));


    Namespace ns = Namespace.getNamespace("g", "http://base.google.com/ns/1.0");

    for (SyndEntry entry : feed.getEntries()) {
        for (Element element : entry.getForeignMarkup()) {
            product.setId(element.getAttribute("id", ns).getValue()); // **id
        }
    }

    System.out.println(product.getId());
} catch (Exception e) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

The part with the `// **id` comment returns a NullPointerException.

What's wrong here? How to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working! The `Namespace` part is not needed and the for is like this:

```
for (SyndEntry entry : feed.getEntries()) {
    for (Element element : entry.getForeignMarkup()) {
        if (element.getQualifiedName().equalsIgnoreCase("g:id")) {
                product.setId(element.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```